# Compactar imagem ao fazer upload com laravel

Tags: php, laravel, upload, file-upload, imagemagick

Gostaria de saber se alguém tem alguma ideia de como proceder para compactar imagem ao fazer upload, pois a imagem está ficando muito grande.

A rotina que estou usando atualmente é a que está abaixo:

```
public function providerUpdateDocuments() {
    $inputs = Input::all();
    $walker_id = Session::get('walker_id');


    foreach ($inputs as $key => $input) {
        $walker_document = WalkerDocument::where('walker_id', $walker_id)->where('document_id', $key)->first();
        if (!$walker_document) {
            $walker_document = new WalkerDocument;
        }
        $walker_document->walker_id = $walker_id;
        $walker_document->document_id = $key;

        if ($input) {
            $file_name = time();
            $file_name .= rand();
            $file_name = sha1($file_name);

            $ext = $input->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $input->move(public_path() . "/uploads", $file_name . "." . $ext);


            $local_url = $file_name . "." . $ext;

            // Upload to S3
            if (Config::get('app.s3_bucket') != "") {
                $s3 = App::make('aws')->get('s3');
                $pic = $s3->putObject(array(
                    'Bucket' => Config::get('app.s3_bucket'),
                    'Key' => $file_name,
                    'SourceFile' => public_path() . "/uploads/" . $local_url,
                ));

                $s3->putObjectAcl(array(
                    'Bucket' => Config::get('app.s3_bucket'),
                    'Key' => $file_name,
                    'ACL' => 'public-read'
                ));

                $s3_url = $s3->getObjectUrl(Config::get('app.s3_bucket'), $file_name);
            } else {
                $s3_url = asset_url() . '/uploads/' . $local_url;
            }




            $get = Walker::where('id', '=', $walker_id)->first();
            $pattern = "Olá, " . $get->first_name . ", ID " . $walker_id . " Documento enviado, aguarde a aprovação.";
            $subject = "Waiting for an Approval";
            /* email_notification('', 'admin', $pattern, $subject); */

            if (isset($walker_document->url)) {
                if ($walker_document->url != "") {
                    $icon = $walker_document->url;
                    unlink_image($icon);
                }
            }

            $walker_document->url = $s3_url;
            $walker_document->save();

            /* if ($walker_document->save()) {
              echo 'asdasd';
              } */
        }
    }

    $message = "Seus documentos foram atualizados com sucesso.";
    $type = "success";
    return Redirect::to('/provider/documents')->with('message', $message)->with('type', $type);
}
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser feito para reduzir o tamanho dessa imagem antes de fazer o upload ou até mesmo após o upload.

Valeu.

Abraço.

Comment: Você pode converter para `webp`; Utilizar o [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) e reduzir um pouco da qualidade; ou poderá utilizar softwares como `jpegoptim`, `optipng` e `pngquant`.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro utilizar o pacote [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/use/uploads), que tem integração com [Laravel](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel)

Um exemplo simples que no upload altera a imagem e salva em disco:

```
<?php
    ...
    class MyController extends Controller

    public function uploadImage(Request $request) {
        // resizing an uploaded file
        Image::make(Input::file('photo'))->resize(300, 200)->save('foo.jpg');
    }
```

Comment: essa função resize() modifica o arquivo em pixels ou em bytes?

Comment: como descrito no manual http://image.intervention.io/api/resize, os parâmetros são width e height, (larg e alt), isso são em pixels ... logicamente o tamanho final vai alterar também